# Why my javascript method cannot get the API from django views function?

Tags: javascript, api, django-views, django-templates

I am very new to javascript, I am doing a project that has a like button. This like button will increase the number of likes of a specific post and change its colour from blue to red when a post is liked.

> views.py

```
@login_required
def likepost(request,id):
    post = NewPost.objects.get(id = id)
    is_like = False
    for like in post.likepost.all():
        if like == request.user and request.method == "POST":
            is_like = True
            break
    
    if not is_like:
        post.likepost.add(request.user)
    
    else:
        post.likepost.remove(request.user)
    
    return JsonResponse({
        "is_like" : is_like,
    })
```

I want this function will work when user clicks on a like button.

> template.html

```
<form action="{% url 'like' id=posts.id %}" method="POST" style="display: inline;" onsubmit="like_function()">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button id = "like" class="btn btn-link" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> {{posts.id}}</button>
    </form>
    <!-- <form action="{% url 'like' id=posts.id %}" method="POST" style="display: inline;" onsubmit="return false">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button onclick="like_function(posts)" id = "like" class="btn btn-link" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> {{posts.id}}</button>
    </form> -->
    <small>{{ posts.likepost.all.count }}</small>
```

Here is my like button and number of likes.

> controller.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    document.querySelector('#like').onsubmit = like_function();
})


function like_function(){
    fetch(`//${like.id}/like`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        if(document.querySelector('#like').style.color == "blue"){
            document.querySelector('#like').style.color = "red";
        }
        else{
            document.querySelector('#like').style.color = "blue"
        }
    })
}
```

This is my full js code. I want this code will fetch API from Django views. When the like button is clicked the button will automatically become red from blue and the number of like will increase without reloading the page. My problem is I can't do anything without reloading also my button is not getting red. It remains blue all the time. How can I solve it?
I am also sharing my models and urls.py file

> models.py

```
class NewPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    post = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    likepost = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=None, blank=True , related_name="likepost")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.post}"
```

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("index/<int:id>/like",views.likepost, name="like"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Submit triggers page reload/redirect to your action. Remove your button's `type=submit` and in your `controller.js` file instead of `onsubmit`, use `onclick`.
You can try this in your `controller.js` file:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    document.querySelector('#like').onclick = like_function();
})


function like_function(){
    fetch(`index/${like.id}/like`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        if(result.is_like){
            document.querySelector('#like').style.color = "red";
        }
        else{
            document.querySelector('#like').style.color = "blue"
        }
    })
}
```